# Finding code tree calling a particular method

Tags: java, methods, intellij-idea

I am working in Intellij and need to know where a given method A is being used. I know i can find it using Find feature, but i need to know the graphical tree structure of classes calling my method A . Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the [Call Hierarchy Window](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/hierarchy-tool-window.html) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> while the cursor is on the method you'd like to view.

[image]